# log4net in ASP.NET Core does not reload on changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, log4net, log4net-configuration

according to [Apache log4net™ Manual - Configuration - appSettings](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) I added these 2 lines to my web.config for watching  changes on my log4net.config file ( e.g changing loglevel during runtime...)

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="log4net.Config" value="log4net.config"/>
  <add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="True"/>
</appSettings>
```

Unfortunately it does not work so that changes on the loglevel will apply without restart of the applicatione. I am working on ASP.Net Core 5.0 and the app uses the appSettings.json instead of web.config.

Comment: _"I am working on ASP.Net Core 5.0"_ - how do you add log4net?

Comment: installed via nuget Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 

adapted the IHostBuilder in CreateHostBuilder as

`.ConfigureLogging(builder =>{
builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
builder.AddLog4Net("log4net.config");
});`

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore, it's as simple as this:

```
services.AddLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.AddLog4Net(new Log4NetProviderOptions { Watch = true });
});
```

Or in your case:

```
services.AddLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.AddLog4Net("log4net.config", true);
});
```

Comment: I removed the ConfigureLogging from the Program.cs and added your mentioned servives.AddLogging to Startup.cs

Unfortunately without success. Loglevel does not change in logfile if I change the value in log4net.config

Comment: The reload works for me if I change the filename in the logging config, for example. Make sure you edit the config in the `bin\Debug\net5.0` directory, and that the changes you make don't conflict with other changes, such as logging thresholds.

Comment: have you an idea, why I cant see DEBUG logs? Even if the level is set to DEBUG or ALL?